# Trouble Getting AJAX GET to work with whitepsace

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a MYSQL table called orgs that has columns for name, city, zip, and state.  I want an AJAX dropdown that populates another field on my page with the name of the cities when I select the name of the city from the dropdown.  I currently have the dropdown for the city updating based on what state I have but when I try the call for the organizations name based on the city my code fails.  Here's what I currently have.

AJAX to get the names of the cities:

```
function list(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","../php/list_org.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

AJAX to get the names of the organizations based on the cities:

```
function get_cities(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("get_cities").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("get_cities").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","../php/get_cities.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

list_org.php:

```
<?php include_once '../php/db_connect.php'; ?>
<?php
$q = strval($_GET['q']);


$sql2="SELECT DISTINCT city FROM orgs WHERE state= '".$q."'";

$result2=mysqli_query($connection,$sql2);

if(!$result2){
      die("Database query failed. " . mysqli_error($connection));
    }

    echo "<form>";
    echo '<select name="get_cities" onchange="get_cities(this.value)">';
    echo '<option value="">Select a city:</option>';
while($row2= mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
    echo '<option value="' . $row2['city']. '">'. $row2['city'].'</option>';
}
    echo "</form>";
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

get_cities.php:

```
<?php include_once '../php/db_connect.php'; ?>
<?php
$q = strval($_GET['q']);
$q='CA';



$sql2="SELECT * FROM orgs WHERE state = '".$q."'";

$result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql2);

if(!$result){
      die("Database query failed. " . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
echo $q;
$link_address = '#';
echo '<div id="get_cities">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<ul>";
  echo "<li><a href='".$link_address."' name='" . $row['id'] ."'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></li>";
  echo "</ul>";
  }
 echo '</div>'




mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

I thought the problem was probably that I was passing cities with whitespace in them (like "los angeles") but I've tried it with single name cities like "Buffalo" and nothing happens when I change my selection either.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. enjoy having your site pwn3d.

Comment: yeah, yeah, I know.  I was going to fix that after I got it to work.

Comment: Change the name of the div from "get_cities" to like "get_cities_div".    Having an object named the same as a function causes issues in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `</select>` in list_org.php. Try to fix that one first, then escape your string.

Replace

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","../php/get_cities.php?q="+str,true);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","../php/get_cities.php?q="+escape(str),true);
```